# Multi Threading and the use of full CPU/GPU capacity

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

> **Hardware**

My computer is `i7-8750H @ 2.20GHz` with `16GB RAM`

and 2 GPUs : one is `Itel UHD Graphics 630` and the other is `Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 with Max Q design`

> **Process**

I have to process `57,000` files through a `java app`

I call `java app` through my `.Net Windows App`

The app processes around `1000 files in 2.5 hours`.

which means complete 6 days non-stop processing (that way too much)

> **Idea**

My understanding that `i7 CPUs` are multiple CPUs (8 i think)

I want to use full CPU and if possible GPU capacity to process these files.

I think multithreading can use more than CPU and speed up the process.
(6 threads to use the 6 CPUs)

> **Code**

This is my code to call the process at the moment

```
        Thread thr1 = new Thread(() => ExecuteCommand(cmdExe1, workingFolder));
        Thread thr2 = new Thread(() => ExecuteCommand(cmdExe2, workingFolder));
        Thread thr3 = new Thread(() => ExecuteCommand(cmdExe3, workingFolder));
        Thread thr4 = new Thread(() => ExecuteCommand(cmdExe4, workingFolder));
        Thread thr5 = new Thread(() => ExecuteCommand(cmdExe5, workingFolder));
        Thread thr6 = new Thread(() => ExecuteCommand(cmdExe6, workingFolder));

        thr1.Start();
        thr2.Start();
        thr3.Start();
        thr4.Start();
        thr5.Start();
        thr6.Start();



    static void ExecuteCommand(string command, string workingFolder)
    {
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingFolder;

        var process = Process.Start(processInfo);

        process.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
            Console.WriteLine("output>>" + e.Data);
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        process.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
            Console.WriteLine("error>>" + e.Data);
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        process.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: {0}", process.ExitCode);
        process.Close();
    }
```

> **Question**

How to use the max `CPU/GPU` capacity and speed up the process

How to `multi-thread` the process?

> **UPDATE**

I have used multithread as in the code yet it is only using 20% of the CPU !

Comment: You need either to start multiple instances of java app (splitting files into multiple subfolders for example) or make it process files in multiple threads. There is not much you can do in the .NET side.

Comment: @GuruStron I tried that but it just use 20% of my processor capacity ! I called 6 multithreads  but it use 20% of my CPU

Comment: Add more instances =)) Also not all performed work can be CPU-bound.

Comment: What happens if you manually run multiple instances of the java program from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an error occure of the app share resources with another instance. I got it fix thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Responding to the update part:
There's a lot of variables to CPU-usage (%). Depending on what is being done to the files you might not be able to max-out your CPU and see usage go to +90%. I'd check disk-usage % (still called disk for SSDs) in your resource monitor; If the data being processed is stored on a hard drive rather then a SSD that might be your limiting factor. If you see disk-usage in the +80% range then your CPU might be getting bottle-necked by read times. Additionally, GPU's can only do very specific tasks when you very clearly and explicitly layout what you want them to do, so unfortunately it's unlikely you'll be able to use hardware acceleration for file processing.

If you're disk-usage is low then hopefully someone smarter then me can give you a better recommendation, good luck!

Comment: Disk is at 6% I dont think this is a bottleneck. from all threads the process seems to be running only once  !